# Galvanized cable wood staples?

Tags: wiring, basement

I am working on wiring my basement and I am adding an outlet to a stud that is green treated. When I attach the wire to the stud with a cable staple, is using one that is zinc coated enough, or does it have to be galvanized like nails need to be?

Answer (score 1):

Pressure treated wood now requires special coated nails (or cable staples). Depending on the exact type of pressure coating, different types of nails are acceptable. It's best to just use stainless steel and be safe...a few won't break the bank. I've heard of a house being torn down because they used uncoated nails and joist hangers.

Answer (score 0):

Standard staples listed for NM cable [like this](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Gardner-Bender-1-2-in-Steel-Staples-for-14-2-12-2-and-10-2-Non-Metallic-Cable-Case-of-6-MS-500J/100182811) are fine. Interior nails many times are glued sinkers not always galvanized because they are not exposed to the weather.

Comment: Did you miss the words "green treated" in the question? My understanding is that OP is using pressure treated wood, if that is case it's recommended to use galvanized, zinc coated etc due to the chemical content of the wood which can oxidize standard steel quickly.  I've never seen anyone use pressure treated wood indoors however.

Comment: I did see green treated. Sill plates are treated and I have never had a problem using standard staples with the copper sulfate or the older arsenic pressure treated lumber in a dry location this is why I mentioned not all nails are galvinised.

Comment: Stainless or coated nails are required in treated lumber because they can be severely degraded by current treatment chemicals. I'd assume the same of uncoated staples.